# Why when I convert string to int I have this, but when I convert from ReadLine it work OK?

Tags: c#, .net

```
double fitstNumber = 3.456;
string str = fitstNumber.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str[2]); // output: 4
int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(str[2]);
Console.WriteLine(secondNumber); // output: 52
```

I tried get second number from string, but in the end, when I convert it to Int32, I get anything else.

Comment: `str[2]` is the unicode character [4](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0034) which corresponds to the numeric value 0x34 = 52.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how a can convert it to Int32?

Comment: What do you expect? 4? Then use `str.Substring(2, 1)` (which is a string) instead of `str[2}` (which is a char).